# how to listen for messages on discord server (that i dont own) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Is it possible to listen for messages on a server that I don't own with JavaScript? I've been looking into discord.js but it sounds like you can only create bots in channels/servers that you're an admin of. I've seen stuff about "self botting" being a bannable offense, but I don't actually want to send messages to the server (sounds like they just don't want it pretending to be a user so I'm thinking my use case should be allowed?). I just want to listen for messages so I can run other JS code on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Although `self bots` are against Discord TOS, they hardly ever ban for them, since they are harmless (if not made maliciously - e.g. token grabbers, nitro code redeemers). Simple answer is yes, just like you can log messages with the `on message` event in discord.js. Technically it is not a self bot if you are not outputting anything or performing discord related functions, and are simply logging what the messages are, then externally performing functions with them outside of discord.